# How to correct interfaceOrientation of viewControllers that weren't in response chain when rotating?

Tags: ios4, screen-orientation

I've build a paginated interface using UIScrollView (something like spring board). Each page has its own view controller as the logic on each page is rather complicated.

The code worked smoothly in portial orientation. Now I need make it to react to orientation changes. But self.interfaceOrientation do not react to orientation changes.

If a controller is invisible during the interface rotation its interfaceOrientation remains unchanged. I suppose that this is because the controller wasn't in the response chain when that rotation happend.

Is there any way to correct the interface orientation programmatically?

I know that I can use `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation` to get the correct orientation but it doesn't look clean to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just propagated the interface orientation change manually down to the page view controllers.